# Ansible Playbook: remote_user is ncorrect ,switching failed

Tags: ansible

I write playbook for download and install and unarchive tar file:

```
 - name: Install DB
     remote_user: ldb
     hosts: db
     tasks:
       - name: Create download directory
         file:
            path: /home/ldb/servicebroker
            state: directory

       - name: download DB and service_broker
         get_url:
             url:  "http://192.168.1.133:12345/stage/{{ item }}"
             dest: /home/ldb/servicebroker
             mode: 0755
             timeout: 30
         with_items:
              - linkoopdb/4.1.0/zettabase-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.iso
              - service_broker/4.1.0/servicebroker-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.tar.gz

       - name: unzip tar file
         unarchive:
           src:  /home/ldb/servicebroker/servicebroker-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.tar.gz
           dest: /home/ldb/servicebroker/

       - name: Start master
         shell: "/home/ldb/servicebroker/brokerServer --master_ip 192.168.14.94  --master_port 7777"

       - name: Start slave
         shell: "/home/ldb/servicebroker/brokerServer brokerServer --master_ip 192.168.14.94 --master_port 7777  --slave_ip {{ item }} --slave_port 7777 join"
         with_items:
            - 192.168.14.95
            - 192.168.14.94
            - 192.168.14.96
            - 192.168.14.97
            - 192.168.14.37
            - 192.168.14.38
            - 192.168.14.39

       - name: Check for servicebroker command
         shell:  /home/ldb/servicebroker/bcli show service_broker，
         register: command_output

       - name: Start create repository and upload  install DB
         shell: "{{ item }}"
         retries: 3
         delay: 10
         register: command_output
         with_items:
           -  /home/ldb/servicebroker/bcli create repository db1
           -  /home/ldb/servicebroker/bcli show repository all
           -  /home/ldb/servicebroker/bcli upload zettabase-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.iso

       - name: Print result
         debug: 
             var: command_output.stdout_lines
```

But run failed and get error info:

```
fatal: [192.168.14.96]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access '/home/ldb/servicebroker/servicebroker-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.tar.gz' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

I found db file owner is root user, not ldb user:

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2162550784 Apr 19 19:36  base-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.iso
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3918489072 Apr 19 19:47  base-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31523406 Apr 19 20:03    servicebroker-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.tar.gz

remote_user: ldb not enable.Please help check! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to look at the error more closely:

```
"Could not find or access '/home/ldb/servicebroker/servicebroker-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.tar.gz' *on the Ansible Controller*.
```

You are downloading the file remotely, but trying to access it locally on the controller. In unarchive where you say:

```
src:  /home/ldb/servicebroker/servicebroker-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.tar.gz
```

Try:

```
src:  /home/ldb/servicebroker/servicebroker-4.1.0-rc6.x86_64.tar.gz
remote_src: yes
```

Note the documentation for unarchive here:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html

Also note: the error is saying the ldb user doesn't have a shell assigned. Ansible can't login as it. Assuming it is the service account to run a service, you probably don't want to make it an interactive user just for Ansible's sake.